# Direct INSERT sql query not working in observer of Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, sql

I am using Event `catalog_category_save_after`. In observer fetch query is working fine but insert and delete query is not working.

Below is my code :

```
  $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
  $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
  $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
  $tableName = $resource->getTableName('catalog_category_product');

  $query = 'INSERT INTO ' . $tableName .' (`category_id`,`product_id`,`position`)VALUES("215","33702","5");';
  $test1 = $writeConnection->query($query);
```

Below querey is generating:

```
INSERT INTO catalog_category_product (`category_id`,`product_id`,`position`)VALUES("215","33702","5");
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue.

Using `catalog_category_save_commit_after` instead of `catalog_category_save_after` did the trick for me.

Alternatively, you can try to use the Magento methods to insert the new row rather than running direct SQL. It should work fine.